# Sonarqube plugin: how to get sonar.projectVersion value?

Tags: sonarqube

I write a custom `PostProjectAnalysisTask`, now I wanna get `sonar.projectVersion` prop value. Anyway to achieve that? thanks in advance.
PS: Mainly do task in `public void finished(ProjectAnalysis analysis){...}`

Answer (score 0):

Need to use `PostJob` and find settings in `PostJobContext`